# Should I returning IQueryable<T> from a repository in DDD

Tags: asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

Recently, I am refactoring my DDD project. When I look at my Repository Layer. I found it return IQueryable< T> in my repository. I am puzzled and should I return IQueryable< T> from a repository in my DDD project in Repository Layer? I usually return IQueryable type in my Repository design. But today I found a opposite idea from this [article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/)
I can't figure it out!

Comment: What should I return in Repository Layer?

Comment: `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyList` seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

If you return `IQueryable` you permit domain knowledge leaking from Domain layer to the consumer layers. It increases the risk that your Domain objects will become anemic and all behavior will move to other layers.

Although it seams very handy to return a `IQueryable` and you think that your code becomes simpler, that is just an illusion; when the project will grow that `IQueryable` will transform your code into a big ball of mud, with domain code scattered every where. You won't be able to optimize your repository or to change one persistence with another (i.e. from sql to nosql).

Comment: Em，and what should I return in `Repository Layer` ? And I found use `Specification Patten` can be a good way.

Comment: @jannagy02 What don't you understand, more precisely?

Comment: I think that this is false information - about leaking domain knowledge, and risk of anemic domain objects and IQueryable transforming your code into a big ball of mud. I do not say that yes you should use IQueryable<T> for returning from repository, it depends on your own needs. And the other answer is more appropriate, this is why I do not understand the why is this accepted.

Comment: Read this book: https://books.google.ro/books?id=iefGBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA507&lpg=PA507&dq=IQueryable+ddd+repository&source=bl&ots=DidbINqzQy&sig=3lQgbHxpmDxgy45GpQ6OewMjMRM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPgvTgo5rUAhUKPhQKHZC0DRAQ6AEIWzAI#v=onepage&q=IQueryable%20ddd%20repository&f=false

Comment: And this article: http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/

Comment: The book writes that it can enable your data model leaking into your domain layer - which is true however you wrote in your answer about domain knowledge leaking which is not true. The article has nothing to do with this topic it is about "generic repository".

Comment: I don't agree. In this context "domain knowledge leaking" is the same as "data model leaking". Also, the same issue regarding Generic repositories applies in this context: you loose control over the queries; you break encapsulation of the Aggregates as you start to depend on specific Entity attributes (name and type).

Comment: @jannagy02 In this way you will have a big ball of mud, a spaghetti code, with Entity attributes (body parts) scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do that.

The repository's job is not only to abstract away persistence details, but also to provide an [**explicit query contract**](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9ebGBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA492&lpg=PA492&dq=repository%20explicit%20query%20contract&source=bl&ots=vdXBg3WZ7O&sig=bEj72jhEj7O4Ou_H4UetzQQybp4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM6uCdl4PSAhXFy1QKHS18COAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=repository%20explicit%20query%20contract&f=false) defining those that are needed to process commands<sup>1</sup> in your domain.

If you feel the need to further filter/transform what's returned from your repository then you most likely failed to capture an explicit query that should be part of the repository's contract.

Having such contract lets the querying clients express their intent and allows for easier optimizations.

*1. Nowadays, it's quite common to apply some CQRS principles and by-bass the domain model entirely for queries. Given this scenario, the only queries that would go through the repository are the ones needed to process commands. You are however not forced in any way to use this approach so your repository could fulfill reporting queries as well if you wish.*